# Open new window on background div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am using CSS to apply a background image to a div tag that wraps all of the content on a website.

```
<div id="mainBack">
  <%-- All other content goes here --%>
</div>
```

And the CSS id with the background property...

```
#mainBack
{
    background: url(../images/background.jpg) repeat-x top;
    padding: 15px 0 20px 0;
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
I'm trying to figure out how to open a new browser window to a different URL whenever the background image is clicked upon. I have tried doing this using jQuery, but the manner in which I implemented it actually causes every click on anything in the website to open a new window. The jQuery click event that does this - although incorrectly - is below:

```
$('#mainBack').click(function () {
    window.open('http://InternalBusProcess:8083/HyperFix.jpg', 'HyperFix');
});
```

Any suggestions on how I can go about implementing this behavior in a fashion that actually works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of `click` events for elements on top of your `#mainBack` element.

For example:

```
<div id="mainBack">
    <a href="#">Some Link</a>
</div>

<script>
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

This will make it so any link clicked on will not allow the event to bubble up to any ancestor elements. Which in turn will make detecting a click on the `#mainBack` element possible.

You will have to stop the propagation of the event on any element you want to be clickable without opening the popup window.

Also, note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 so if you're using an older version, change `.on()` to `.bind()`.

### Update

You can also use the `event` object inside your event handler to check if the targeted element is the `#mainBack` element:

```
$('#mainBack').click(function (event) {
    if (event.target.id == 'mainBack') {
        window.open('http://InternalBusProcess:8083/HyperFix.jpg', 'HyperFix');
    }
});
```

Here is a demo of using `event.target`: http://jsfiddle.net/j5NuW/ (notice the event handler is attached to the `body` element but the alert only shows if you click the `#mainBack` element)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jasper. One question - the .on() doesn't seem to be recognized though.

Comment: Use .bind then. On is new in jquery 1.7.

Comment: Ok, that's the direction I thought you were going with it, but I wasn't sure. Anyway, I opted for the latter solution actually, and it works great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the clicked element was the div or something else by adding one line of code, and the event parameter to the function:

```
$('#mainBack').click(function (event) {
    if(event.target==this)
        window.open('http://InternalBusProcess:8083/HyperFix.jpg', 'HyperFix');
});
```